# Activity lifecycle in PiP

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, picture-in-picture

I know there's a lot of questions on activity lifecycle of Android activities on StackOverflow, but I am asking specifically for the activity lifecycle in PiP(picture in picture) mode.

Is the activity recreated during PiP mode (`onStop()`, `onCreate()`, etc), are called, or does the activity maintain its paused state throughout PiP?

Comment: When your activity switches to PIP, the system places the activity in the paused state and calls the activity's onPause() method. Video playback should not be paused and should continue playing if the activity is paused while in PIP mode. When your activity switches out of PIP mode back to full-screen mode, the system resumes your activity and calls your onResume() method.

Comment: I know `onPause()` is called, but is the activity recreated? i.e. is `onCreate()` called? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the Android documentation, When your activity switches to PIP, the system places the activity in the paused state and calls the activity's onPause() method.